# How to download a jar file in corda on entering the hash value?

Tags: corda

I have tried to upload a zip file and got the hash. Now I have called an api. In that I am giving the hash to download the file. But I am not able to download the file.

```
@PUT
@Path("download_file")
fun createIOU(
        @QueryParam("sechash") sechash: String
): Response {

    val SecuHash = SecureHash.parse(sechash)
    return try {
        val attachmentJr = downloadAttachment(rpcOps, SecuHash)
        println("jar      :"+attachmentJr)
        Response.status(CREATED).entity("Transaction id ${attachmentJr} committed to ledger.\n").build()
    } catch (ex: Throwable) {
        logger.error(ex.message, ex)
        Response.status(BAD_REQUEST).entity(ex.message!!).build()
    }
}

private fun downloadAttachment(proxy: CordaRPCOps, attachmentHash: SecureHash) {
    //Get the attachmentJar from node for attachmentHash.
    val attachmentJar = proxy.openAttachment(attachmentHash)
    //Read the content of Jar to get file name and data.
    var file_name_data: Pair<String, ByteArray>? = null
    JarInputStream(attachmentJar).use { jar ->
        while (true) {
            val nje = jar.nextEntry ?: break
            if (nje.isDirectory) {
                continue
            }
            file_name_data = Pair(nje.name, jar.readBytes())

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check the node's web logs and see if there is a stack trace? If so, can you post it?

Comment: The `downloadAttachment` function should return `file_name_data` value to caller... So modify fun defination to add return type as `Pair<String, ByteArray>` and return value of `file_name_data` inside the given fun.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this blog. It explains in great details how to achieve upload and download of attachments in Corda.

It demonstrates the download of an attachment using two different approaches:

**Using attachmentId/ hash**

```
@GetMapping("/{hash}")
fun downloadByHash(@PathVariable hash: String): ResponseEntity<Resource> {
    val inputStream = InputStreamResource(proxy.openAttachment(SecureHash.parse(hash)))
    return ResponseEntity.ok().header(
        HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
        "attachment; filename=\"$hash.zip\""
    ).body(inputStream)
}
```

**Using the name of the attachment**

```
@GetMapping
fun downloadByName(@RequestParam name: String): ResponseEntity<Resource> {
  val attachmentIds: List<AttachmentId> = proxy.queryAttachments(
    AttachmentQueryCriteria.AttachmentsQueryCriteria(filenameCondition = Builder.equal(name)),
    null
  )
  val inputStreams = attachmentIds.map { proxy.openAttachment(it) }
  val zipToReturn = if (inputStreams.size == 1) {
    inputStreams.single()
  } else {
    combineZips(inputStreams, name)
  }
  return ResponseEntity.ok().header(
    HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
    "attachment; filename=\"$name.zip\""
  ).body(InputStreamResource(zipToReturn))
}

private fun combineZips(inputStreams: List<InputStream>, filename: String): InputStream {
  val zipName = "$filename-${UUID.randomUUID()}.zip"
  FileOutputStream(zipName).use { fileOutputStream ->
    ZipOutputStream(fileOutputStream).use { zipOutputStream ->
      inputStreams.forEachIndexed { index, inputStream ->
        val zipEntry = ZipEntry("$filename-$index.zip")
        zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(zipEntry)
        inputStream.copyTo(zipOutputStream, 1024)
      }
    }
  }
  return try {
    FileInputStream(zipName)
  } finally {
    Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get(zipName))
  }
}
```

https://lankydan.dev/uploading-and-downloading-attachments-in-corda

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)